# Suitability of gmail for sending transactional email through ASP.NET C# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gmail, transactional

I was not sure what StackExchange site to put this under, but as it is (sort of) related to programming I am posting it in here.

I am developing a web application which will send a maximum of around 700 emails a week (it is likely that this will be concentrated around a few consecutive days in a week). When I made a prototype of this application, I used my gmail account to send these, however, as it is imperative that the emails are sent, I wondered if someone could give advice as to whether gmail would be able to handle this (from a technical perspective and their Terms of Service), and if not, whether there were any suggestions about an email service that could handle this (preferably a free alternative!).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've heard good things about [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/), and you can send 200 emails per day for free and it's something ridiculously cheap like 10 cents per thousand after that.

Comment: Also there's [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) and [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/).  The former is technical, the latter is well-suited to turn over to your marketing dept.  SES is especially [cheap](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/).

Comment: You could also take a look at [AlphaMail](http://comfirm.se).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I have taken a look at them all. Mandrill would be the cheapest option (it is free for up to 12k emails a month - http://mandrill.com/pricing/). However, I am leaning towards using Amazon SES just because I already use Amazon, and the cost is negligible. I will prototype with a couple of them though just to see what service I like the most.

Comment: I know this is quite old, but for anyone that may stumble upon this in future. I've used Mandrill, Sendgrid, and Postmarkapp. Had problems getting Mandrill to play nice with DNS settings. Postmarkapp was just butt slow. I've settled on Sendgrid in the end. Sendgrid wants to review your registration before letting you play (at least that's what person who was in charge of setting it up claims), but it has a free tier if you want to try it, and it's got almost instantaneous delivery.